# How to print 5 byte integer values?

Tags: c

I've just started reading C and have a question about a macro.
How can I print a 5 byte integer value (that happens to be defined in a macro)? 
For example:

```
#define MAX 0xdeadbeaf12
int main(){
printf(" 0x %2x \n", MAX);
}
```

This code prints adbeaf12 but not deadbeaf12.

How do I get all the bytes printed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to make my assumptions about the size of a variable explicit. The following uses standard (though often unused) macros to define a 64-bit constant and print such a quantity as a hex value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Pull in UINT64_C and PRIx64 macros
#include <inttypes.h>

// Make this a 64-bit literal value
#define MAX UINT64_C(0xdeadbeaf12)

int main()
{
    // Use PRIx64 which inserts the correct printf specifier for
    // a hex format of a 64-bit value
    printf(" 0x%" PRIx64 " \n", MAX);
}
```

Comment: +1 for UINT64_C() from §7.18.4.1 of the C99 standard (and PRIx64, which is consistent with the question, though I'd use PRIX64 for preference).

Comment: For the original poster's benefit, PRIx64 will print lowercase hex digits, while PRIX64 will print uppercase.

Comment: `PRIx64` is not the matching specifier for `UINT64_C()`.  `PRIxLEAST64` is the matching one.  "The macro `UINTN_C`(value) shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type `uint_leastN_t`."

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MAX 0xdeadbeaf12LL
```

Will tell the compiler to use the longest available integer type (which will then be cast to an appropriate type wherever `MAX` is used).

On most platforms, the numeric literal suffix `LL` will correspond to `signed long long`, this is 64bit (8 bytes) on a 32 bit system. C's excellent typing system and compiler warnings will take care of the rest for you.

Your `printf` then needs to use the `ll` modifier:

```
printf(" 0x %2llx \n", MAX);
```

Comment: This is all to no avail if you do not also fix the printf() format string.  It says 'print an unsigned int'; if 'unsigned int' is 4 bytes, it is not going to print more.  You might be lucky and get to see the low-order 4 bytes (on a little-endian machine); on a big-endian machine, you would see a different value.  On both types of machine, the alignment of arguments after the 64-bit integer would be completely off - leading to problems.

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem. But note I used "most platforms". No platform was given, I think maybe complicating things more than than necessary (the obvious error in OP is that MAX is cast to a 4 byte integer) will only confuse the matter here.

Comment: The "Greatest-width integer types" are `intmax_t/ uintmax_t`.  `long long` is not necessarily the longest available integer type